# Абстрактный generic класс, с переменным числом типов

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Меня интересует может ли `generic` класс принимать несколько типов параметров, а точнее которое заранее неизвестно, как тот же кортеж?

Т.е. на данный момент у меня есть 2 класса, с одним именем, но при этом они оба абстрактные, и один из них не является `generic`'ом.

```
public abstract class SafeLibrary : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    private Dictionary<string, Delegate> _cashedFunctions;

    public string ModulePath { get; }

    private SafeLibrary() : base(true)
    {
        _cashedFunctions = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
    }

    protected SafeLibrary(string modulePath) : this()
    {
        handle = WinApi.LoadLibrary(modulePath);
        if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        ModulePath = modulePath;
    }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        bool result = WinApi.FreeLibrary(handle);
        handle = result ? IntPtr.Zero : handle;
        if (!result)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        _cashedFunctions.Clear();
        _cashedFunctions = null;

        return result;
    }

    public T GetInteropDelegate<T>() where T : Delegate
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);

        if (type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute), false).Length == 0)
        {
            throw new AttributeNotFoundException($"Attribute with type {typeof(T).FullName} has no UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute!");
        }

        object[] attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CFunctionAttribute), false);
        if (attributes == null || attributes.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new AttributeNotFoundException($"Attribute with type {typeof(T).FullName} has no CFunctionAttribute!");
        }

        string funcName = (attributes[0] as CFunctionAttribute).Function;

        if (_cashedFunctions.ContainsKey(funcName))
        {
            return (T)_cashedFunctions[funcName];
        }

        T result = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<T>(WinApi.GetProcAddress(handle, funcName));
        _cashedFunctions.Add(funcName, result);
        return result;
    }
}

public abstract class SafeLibrary<DependsModule> : SafeLibrary where DependsModule : SafeLibrary, new()
{
    public DependsModule DependedModule
    {
        get;
    }

    protected SafeLibrary(string modulePath) :
        base(modulePath)
    {
        DependedModule = new DependsModule();
    }
}
```

Таким образом, можно избавиться от необходимости ручной подгрузки необходимых зависимостей библиотеки:

```
class MySafeLibraryClass : SafeLibrary
{
    public MySafeLibraryClass() : base("SomePathToNeededModule.dll")
    {
    }
}

class MySafeLibraryClassWithDepends : SafeLibrary<MySafeLibraryClass>
{
    public MySafeLibraryClassWithDepends() : base("SomePathToNeededModule.dll")
    {
    }
}
```

Но, что если у библиотеки *(одной)* имеется несколько зависимостей, заново подгружать эти библиотеки вручную?

В общем, хотелось бы иметь примерно такой вид:

```
class MySafeLibraryClass : SafeLibrary
{
    public MySafeLibraryClass() : base("SomePathToNeededModule.dll")
    {
    }
}

class MySafeLibraryClass2 : SafeLibrary
{
    public MySafeLibraryClass() : base("SomePathToNeededModule2.dll")
    {
    }
}

class MySafeLibraryClass3 : SafeLibrary
{
    public MySafeLibraryClass() : base("SomePathToNeededModule3.dll")
    {
    }
}

class MySafeLibraryClassWithDepends : SafeLibrary<MySafeLibraryClass, MySafeLibraryClass2, MySafeLibraryClass3> // и т.д. Заранее неизвестно сколько зависимостей.
{
    public MySafeLibraryClassWithDepends() : base("SomePathToNeededModuleWithDepends.dll")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Кортеж не принимает переменное число типов, он просто имеет гору перегрузок

Comment: Но его восьмая перегрузка говорит о том что ему плевать сколько ему передали типов. По крайней мере описание такое.

Comment: не понял о чем вы. Вот это `Tuple.Create(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);` не компилится. Это тоже не компилится `var ret = new System.Tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);`

Comment: @tym32167: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-8.-ctor?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DRU-RU%26k%3Dk(System.ValueTuple%608.%2523ctor)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.7.2)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: `Экземпляр любого типа кортежа значений, который содержит значения остальных элементов кортежа значений.` - последний параметр - другой кортеж, а не элемент кортежа

Comment: [`var primes = new Tuple<Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Tuple<Int32>> (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, new Tuple<Int32>(19));`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-8?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: тогда это похоже на односвязный список...

Comment: ну что то типа. Первые 7 типов как даннык в кортеже, 8й тип как указатель на след кортеж

Comment: Когда вы пишите вот так - `handle = WinApi.LoadLibrary(modulePath);` - вы теряете преимущества SafeHandle. Импортированный метод LoadLibrary должен возвращать SafeLibrary.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, но как такого добиться?

Comment: @LLENN отказаться от отдельного класса на каждую библиотеку конечно же

Comment: @LLENN кстати, метод ReleaseHandle не должен кидать исключений, у него для этого возвращаемый `bool` есть

Comment: @LLENN кстати, вы никак не ограничиваете вызов делегатов после ReleaseHandle, это тоже неправильно